# Email HTML: How do I arrange 2 buttons in one line, but have them stretch to the full size of the container?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I layout html letter, everything was going well until I needed to place in one line two buttons of different sizes and across the width of the content. Tried for half a day to solve this problem myself, without success. So, please help me solve this button problem, but in a way that doesn't break the code. I am new to html-email

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
  <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark" />
  <title>title</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');

    table {
      border-spacing: 0;
      mso-cellspacing: 0;
      mso-padding-alt: 0;
    }

    td {
      padding: 0;
    }

    #outlook a {
      padding: 0;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #e8fbfa;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  </style>

  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style type="text/css">
      table {border-collapse: collapse !important;}
    </style>
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      <o:AllowPNG/>
      <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  </xml>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body style="Margin:0;padding:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#FFFFFF;">

   <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <style type="text/css">
         body {background-color: #dde0e1!important;}
         body, table, td, p, a {font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica!important;}
      </style>
   <![endif]-->

   <center style="width: 100%;table-layout:fixed;background-color: #FFFFFF;padding-top: 40px;padding-bottom: 40px;">
    <div style="padding: 20px 16px 20px 16px; max-width: 600px;background-color: #F6F6F6;box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);">

      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="600" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"
          style="color:#1C1E23;">
        <tr>
        <td>
      <![endif]-->

      <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"
        style="color: #060B13;font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;background-color: #F6F6F6;Margin:0;padding:0;width: 100%;max-width: 600px;"
        >
          <!-- SECTION 1 -->
          <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0 25px 0 25px;" bgcolor="#E3F7FE">
              <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 10px 0 0px 0;">
                    <p style="margin: 0; color: #060B13; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px; text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 0px 0 0px 0;">
                    <p style="margin: 0; color: #060B13; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px; text-align: center;">Consequuntur veniam nostrum perferendis saepe?</p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 0px 0 30px 0;">
                    <p style="margin: 0; color: #060B13; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px; text-align: center;">Dignissimos saepe explicabo quae asperiores!</p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- END SECTION 1 -->

           <!-- SECTION 2 -->
           <tr>
            <td style="padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px; font-size: 0;" bgcolor="#E3F7FE">
              <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align: top; display: inline-block;">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 20px 0 0;">
                          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #FEC833; border-radius: 5px;">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank" style="background-color: #FEC833; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; color: #060B13; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; line-height: 20px; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ДЕТЕКТИВЫ&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align: top; display: inline-block;">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #FEC833; border-radius: 5px;">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank" style="background-color: #FEC833; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; color: #060B13; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; line-height: 20px; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗАРУБЕЖНАЯ ЛИТЕРАТУРА&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <!-- END SECTION 2 -->
      </table>

      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      <![endif]-->

    </div>
  </center>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest to manage the width of buttons, especially when they are of different sizes, you can use percentage widths or fixed widths in your tables. This will help you control how much space each button occupies.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com, I tried using **%**, but unfortunately the size of the tables can only be set in **px (220px, 360px)** if the container size is **600px**. Partially px solves the problem by stretching the buttons to the desired size, but when adapting the buttons are split into 2 rows and it is impossible to resize them. So it remains that one button is **220px** and the other **360px**, even `width: 100%` didn't help :(. I hope I have explained it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two elements to be positioned side by side in an email (and you need them to stack for mobile users) try using tables. Align one table to the left, the other to the right. Set the tables to be 49% so there's some wiggle room (Outlook may stack two 50% tables). This wiggle room works in your case because it'll give you a little room between each button.

Here's a pretty sturdy example.  Take note of the two button tables.  Also noticed the style that instructs the "button" class to go to 100% when the viewport is less than 600px. I hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!--[if !mso]><!--><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><!--<![endif]-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
  <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
  <title>SUBJECT_HERE</title>
  <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .button{ width: 100% !important; }
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body style="background: #ffffff; height:100% !important; width:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; ">
<table class="in-dark-bgcolor-262626" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff; border-spacing:0 !important; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size:0;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="in-dark-bgcolor-262626" width="600" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="border-spacing:0 !important; border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
            

            <!-- Button -->
            <table class="button" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="49%" align="left" role="presentation" style="margin-bottom:2%;">
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#fec833" height="40" style="border-radius:5px;">
                  <a href="/" target="_blank" style="display:block; text-decoration:none; font-family: sans-serif; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; line-height:40px; color:#060b13;">
                    ДЕТЕКТИВЫ
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- Button -->
            <table class="button" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="49%" align="right" role="presentation">
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#fec833" height="40" style="border-radius:5px;">
                  <a href="/" target="_blank" style="display:block; text-decoration:none; font-family: sans-serif; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; line-height:40px; color:#060b13;">
                    ЗАРУБЕЖНАЯ ЛИТЕРАТУРА
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="font-size:0;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```